# O que significa "por onde ele anda?"

Tags: gramática, expressões

O que significa "por onde ele anda"?

Eu vi em um texto "eu não o tenho visto ultimamente. Por onde ele anda?"

Isso é uma expressão que significa "onde ele estava?"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

É uma pergunta genérica com algumas possibilidades: Pode se referir a querer saber onde está neste momento e no passado recente, bem como 'o que anda fazendo', enfim, um pedido de 'contexto' a respeito da pessoa no tempo presente/passado recente.

Answer (score 2):

Quem faz essa pergunta está querendo saber **"por onde ele anda"**, com o verbo andar sendo usado com **o significado 11 do Priberam**:

> - achar-se, encontrar-se (ex.: ele andava no Norte do país, não sei bem onde). = ESTAR
>     https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/andar

- "Por onde anda o João? Eu não o vejo há algum tempo."
- "Também não o tenho visto. Acho está viajando."

Na maioria das vezes, quem faz a pergunta **está querendo dizer que não vê o fulano/a há algum ou há muito tempo, e ao mesmo tempo deseja saber se o seu interlocutor tem notícias daquela pessoa.**

Mas a expressão "por onde anda" **não é usada só para pessoas**. Em minha própria região frequentemente usamos algo do tipo: "Ei, fulano, você sabe **por onde anda aquele alicate** que meu pai usava para arrancar pregos e grampos?" (significa que não vejo o objeto há muito tempo e estou perguntando sobre o seu paradeiro)