# verbo transitivo x verbo intransitivo - Estaria o dicionário errado?

Tags: transitividade-verbal, verbos-intransitivos, verbos-transitivos

Ao responder a [**uma outra pergunta**](https://portuguese.stackexchange.com/questions/5123/o-que-significa-por-onde-ele-anda), fui buscar no Priberam a referência para a resposta (os significados do verbo "andar")  Encontrei difinições numeradas de 01 a 09 para seu uso como verbo intransitivo, e de **10 a 15 como verbo transitivo**, com os respectivos exemplos copiados abaixo:

10. Caminhar durante determinada extensão (ex.: andou um metro e caiu). = PERCORRER
11. Achar-se, encontrar-se (ex.: ele andava no Norte do país, não sei bem onde). = ESTAR
12. Deslocar-se com um meio de transporte (ex.: andar de carro; andar a cavalo).
13. Corresponder aproximadamente a (ex.: o preço anda pelos 2€).
14. Estar ocupado numa .atividade (ex.: ele anda na jardinagem).
15. Estar acompanhado por (ex.: não andes com estranhos).

"andar", in Dicionário Priberam da Língua Portuguesa [em linha], 2008-2013, https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/andar [consultado em 05-02-2018].

Não me parece que o verbo **andar**, com esses significados e exemplos, seja um verbo transitivo. Onde estariam os objetos direto e indireto?
Em "ele andou um metro", não entendo "um metro" como objeto do verbo andar.

Comparo esse exemplo com "O nível do rio subiu dois metros", onde "subir" é um verbo intransitivo e "dois metros" não é objeto do verbo.
**Nos exemplos acima, de 10 a 15, o verbo andar é transitivo?  Existe objeto direto e/ou indireto? Ou existem predicativos do sujeito?**

Comment: Se você dissesse o motivo do downvote ajudaria a melhorar a qualidade das perguntas.  A dúvida é real e procurei seguir o padrão preconizado pelo PL na redação.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O termo *transitivo* pode ser usado com vários significados, mas de facto o Priberam não parece usar o termo consistentemente. Veja-se [esta pergunta](https://www.flip.pt/Duvidas-Linguisticas/Duvida-Linguistica/DID/4788) de 2003:

> Apesar de, actualmente, o verbo prescindir dever ser considerado um verbo transitivo indirecto, como faz o Aurélio, a classificação mais tradicional em dicionários portugueses (diferentemente de dicionários brasileiros como o Aurélio ou o Houaiss) é classificar verbos com regência de proposições que não sejam a (como "entregar a") como intransitivos (como é o caso de "prescindir de"). Em casos semelhantes, é normal encontrar discrepâncias entre dicionários portugueses e brasileiros, sendo a classificação dos segundos geralmente mais rigorosa.

No entanto, a [atual entrada de *prescindir*](https://www.priberam.pt/dlpo/prescindir) marca-o como transitivo. O dicionário parece marcar consistentemente (1) os pronominais (de vários tipos: inerente em *lembrar-se*, recíproco *agredirem-se*, reflexo em *lavar-se* e anti-causativo *fechar-se*, transitivos-predicativos reflexos como em *o João afirmou-se o maior*), (2) os copulativos ou de ligação (que designa por *verbos copulativos*, como *ser*, *estar*, *ficar* e também andar), (3) transitivos diretos, (4) transitivos-predicativos como *considerar* e *achar* e (5) os verbos transitivos diretos e indiretos, como *oferecer*, que são marcados com *verbo transitivo*.

Onde a porca torce o rabo é nos verbos transitivos indiretos (quer selecionem complemento indireto quer oblíquo). Neste caso, podem ser marcados ou como intransitivos, ou como transitivos:

- *convir*, *agradar*, *pertencer* (argumento interno objecto indireto) estão marcados como intransitivo.
- *telefonar*, *recorrer* (argumento interno objeto indireto) está marcado como transitivo. Há quem considere o argumento interno de *recorrer* oblíquo (substituição por *lhe* não é possível).
- *prescindir*, *abdicar*,  *acreditar*, *morar* (argumento interno oblíquo) estão marcados como transitivos.
- *concorrer*, *insistir*, *viver* (=morar) (argumento interno oblíquo) estão marcados como intransitivos.

Não vejo de facto muita consistência.

O significado mais comum de *verbo transitivo* é talvez o de *verbo transitivo direto*. O [Dicionário Terminológico](http://dt.dge.mec.pt/) define-o assim:

> Verbo principal que selecciona um sujeito e um complemento com a função sintáctica de complemento directo (i)-(iv). Exemplos:
>   (i) A Ana fechou a porta.
>   (ii) A Ana fechou-a.
>   (iii) *A Ana fechou. (agramatical como frase isolada)
>   (iv) A Ana afirmou [que tinham fechado a porta].
>   (v) A Ana afirmou-o.
>   (vi) *A Ana pediu. (agramatical como frase isolada)

(Nesta definição, o verbo *haver* não é *transitivo direto*, pois não seleciona um argumento com função sujeito.)

Existem ainda definições de transitividade mais estritas do que esta. A tradicional é a de que os verbos *transitivos* são aqueles que podem «transitar» da voz ativa para a passiva. Nesta definição, verbos como *custar* e *medir* (por exemplo, em *ele mede quase dois metros*) não são transitivos.

Comment: A confusão é grande porque falta uma nomenclatura padrão.  O que muitos chamam de verbo transitivo predicativo ou copulativo, eu aprendi como sendo verbos de ligação.

Comment: @Centaurus estava a misturar aqui os predicativos (ou de ligação, ou copulativos, que levam um predicativo do sujeito) como _ser_ com os transitivos-predicativos (como _considerar_, onde há um predicativo do complemento direto). Corrigi essa parte.

Comment: *A tradicional é a de que os verbos transitivos são aqueles que podem «transitar» da voz ativa para a passiva.*  foi assim que aprendi na escola, pelo menos no que se refere aos "transitivos diretos".